# How can I save a dictionary to Firebase in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dictionary of type [Int: Int] that I am trying to save to firebase.  My function for writing to firebase looks like this:

```
func writeToFirebase() {
    setScoreToBadge()
    setScoreToVehicle()
    if GameManager.instance.getUsername() != "" {
        self.ref?.child("user").child(
                GameManager.instance.getUsername()
        ).setValue(
            [
                "email": GameManager.instance.getEmail(),
                 "userNameLowered": GameManager.instance.getUsername().lowercased(),
                 "userName": GameManager.instance.getUsername(),
                 "topScore": GameManager.instance.getTopScores()[0],
                 "topScores": GameManager.instance.getTopScores(),
                 "totalCash": GameManager.instance.getTotalCash(),
                 "friends": GameManager.instance.getFriendsAdded(),
                 "achievements": GameManager.instance.getAchievementsCompletedBool(),
                 "badge": GameManager.instance.getBadgeLevel(),
                 "scoreBadgeDictionary" : GameManager.instance.getTopScoreWithBadgeDictionary(),
                 "scoreVehicleDictionary" : GameManager.instance.getTopScoreWithVehicleDictionary()
            ])
    } else {
        print ("Not signed in, score not saved to firebase")
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with `scoreBadgeDictionary` and `, scoreVehiceDictionary`.  `GameManager.instance.getTopScoreWithBadgeDictionary()` is a dictionary of type `[Int: Int]` and `GameManager.instance.getTopScoreWithVehicleDictionary()` is a dictionary of type `[Int: String]`.  If I try to run this function it will crash.

Is there a way to convert the dictionary to a format that I can save to firebase?

Comment: If there's a crash, please edit your question to include the exact error message and the stack trace.

Comment: Short answer is that Firebase keys must be strings with the exception that an array in Firebase has numeric indexes. That being said, what is the use case for a dictionary with a numeric key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is how the array is defined. A simple example

```
let myArray = ["some_key": "some_value"]
```

is defined as an array of [String: String]

and

```
let myArray = ["some_key": 5]
```

is defined as an array of [String: Int]

Your array is

```
[
"email": GameManager.instance.getEmail(),
"userNameLowered": GameManager.instance.getUsername().lowercased(),
.
.
"scoreBadgeDictionary" : ["some key": "some value"]
]
```

where, I assume GameManager.instance.getTopScoreWithBadgeDictionary() returns a dictionary.

So that array doesn't conform to [String: String] or [String: Int]. However it does conform to a more generic [String: Any] so that's what you need to 'tell' the var.

```
let myArray: [String: Any] = [
     "email": "Hello",
     "userNameLowered": "hello",
     "scoreBadgeDictionary" : [1: "some score"],
     "scoreVehicleDictionary" : [2: "some vehicle"]
]
```

However, and this is the important bit, the dictionaries returned in `getTopScoreWithVehicleDictionary` which is a [Int: String] or [Int: Int] is not going to work with Firebase.

Firebase keys **must be strings** so attempting to write this [1: "Hello, World] will crash. Noting that arrays in Firebase have numeric indexes and

> if the data looks like an array, Firebase will render it as an array.

I would suggest rethinking that structure - possibly cast the Int's to a string would be an option but that may not work for your use case.